# MySQL Update multiple records with One Update Statement

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a dynamically generated UPDATE Statements from which looks like this:

```
UPDATE `maildespatch` SET `RL_TktNumber`= Null ,`SxRemote_IP`= '::1' ,`SxRemotename`= 'Raks' WHERE `Table_ID` = 1 , 
UPDATE `maildespatch` SET `RL_TktNumber`= Null ,`SxRemote_IP`= '::1' ,`SxRemotename`= 'Raks' WHERE `Table_ID` = 2 , 
UPDATE `maildespatch` SET `RL_TktNumber`= Null ,`SxRemote_IP`= '::1' ,`SxRemotename`= 'Raks' WHERE `Table_ID` = 5 , 
UPDATE `maildespatch` SET `RL_TktNumber`= Null,`SxRemote_IP`= '::1' ,`SxRemotename`= 'Raks' WHERE `Table_ID` = '68'
```

The data comes from the user-input on HTML Table Fields based on which these statements are generated dynamically through ajax() call. Is there a way to save all this data to be saved/Updated in MySQL more generically? I do not want to create a temporary MySQL Table to save data and then from update the Main Table.

Comment: How are you passing these four queries data to server? Array or like what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more generic approach would be calling a stored procedure (a.k.a user defined function - UDF) in mysql and passing the necessary parameters.

Stored procedures are reusable piece of code on your database (like functions in your backend code) that can encapsulate a piece of logic. Take a look at MYSQL documentation for stored procedures [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html).

Using them, you can be as generic as you want - for example have defaults for values that are passed most often (like your `SxRemote_IP = '::1' ,SxRemotename = 'Raks'`)so you don't have to send them over the network and omit them in your front end code.

Comment: Seems to be logical but I will need guidance of UDF stored procedure. Ok give me some time to refresh myself on it and If I fail I will bother you.

Answer (score 1):

You can run those 4 queries as one like below:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

    $sql = "UPDATE `maildespatch` SET `RL_TktNumber`= '11',`SxRemote_IP`= '::1' ,`SxRemotename`= 'Raks'  WHERE `Table_ID` = '1'; 
            UPDATE `maildespatch` SET `RL_TktNumber`= 'Null',`SxRemote_IP`= '::1' ,`SxRemotename`= 'Raks'  WHERE `Table_ID` = '2'; 
            UPDATE `maildespatch` SET `RL_TktNumber`= '33',`SxRemote_IP`= '::1' ,`SxRemotename`= 'Raks'  WHERE `Table_ID` = '5';
            UPDATE `maildespatch` SET `RL_TktNumber`= 'Null',`SxRemote_IP`= '::1' ,`SxRemotename`= 'Raks'  WHERE `Table_ID` = '68'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

or you can do loop if you are passing data as array:

```
foreach ($alldata as $data)
{
    //your queries will go here
}
```

Comment: Ok. I agree that I need to replace `,` with` ;` at end of each `UPDATE` statement. But this is too much network intensive. Any disruption on connectivity will compromise the `DB` integrity.

Comment: You can create STORE PROCEDURE that will contain all code with UPDATE statements.

Comment: Working on Stored Procedure Now because MySQL doesn't allow multiple `UPDATE SQL`  like `UPDATE ...;  UPDATE....;....`  from PHP. It is throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE maildespatch
SET RL_TktNumber = CASE WHEN Table_ID = '1' THEN '11'
                        WHEN Table_ID = '2' THEN NULL
                        WHEN Table_ID = '5' THEN '33'
                        WHEN Table_ID = '68' THEN NULL END,
    SxRemote_IP = '::1',
    SxRemotename = 'Raks'
WHERE
    Table_ID = IN('1', '2', '5', '68');
```

Note that if `Table_ID` be an integer column, then rightfully you should be comparing against integers, e.g. the `WHERE` clause should look like this:

```
WHERE Table_ID = IN(1, 2, 5, 68)
```

Comment: This approach is Case Specific. Since the statements are going to change as per the User Inputs, will this kind of statement be used?

Comment: @Raky Maybe we could setup some sort of prepared statement.  This is the only way I know to do all your updates in a single statement.

Comment: Please close duplicate questions instead of answering them.